# C# Image AS3 ByteArray

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amf, fluorinefx

I'm looking for the conventer from normal image in C# to AMF3 `ByteArray`. The image format is JPG, I'm using FluorineFX library to serialize and de-serliazize AMF3 Data.

I need to get image `ByteArray` in C# from JPG because I'm using this to my flash game, and I don't know how to serialize image to AMF3 `ByteArray`. There isn't much info on FluorineFX neither AMF3 C# `ByteArray`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

According to old FluorineFX Documentation if you want to convert image to byte array you need to use byte[] (variable types ending with [] are arrays) or FluorineFx.AMF3.ByteArray.
byte[] Example code:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that dosent return proper ByteArray i need, that bytearray is stored in array, not the string + flash dosent accept that bytearray i did with your code snippet